# Class not found in project sources or resources GWT

Tags: java, maven, gwt

I'm building GWT application with Maven. My application uses some custom UI forms instead of standard ones. I have files with custom UI forms, packed in `.jar` file.

My `.ui.xml` file has this:

```
<ui:UiBinder xmlns:ui='urn:ui:com.google.gwt.uibinder'
             xmlns:g='urn:import:com.google.gwt.user.client.ui'
             xmlns:nc='custompackage.gwt.fields.client.widgets.reference'
>
...    
<nc:UIReferenceField width="100%" text = "123" nc:field="rf"/>
...
```

My module `.gwt.xml` file inherits custom class:

```
...
<inherits name="custompackage.gwt.fields.Fields"/>
...
```

When I build Maven module I get:

> ```
> Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:gwt-maven-plugin:2.6.0:compile (default)
> on project geographical-view-for-osp-gwt-2: GWT Module
> com.netcracker.platform.ui.toolkit.gwt.i18n.i18n not found in project sources or resources.
> ```

I've looked into similar problem questions, but their resolution didn't help me at all. Can you help me?

P.S.: My module builds fine without custom fields.

Comment: Could you please post the `custompackage.gwt.fields.Fields.gwt.xml` file? Is that file contained in the `.jar`? Do you provide [a source artifact](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-source-plugin) of that .jar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didnt add some dependencies to my .pom file. My inherited module depended on them and it didnt compile.

Comment: @Ajax yes, I have.